# JSON response getting cutoff

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express

Made an express server to call an api. We've managed to successfully request the JSON object in our server. Our problem now is having it display as a complete JSON object in client. The json data is being cutoff when the server requests from the api. Any suggestions? I have tried parse instead of stringify but get this error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input 
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at fetch.then.x (/Users/server.js:26:19)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Here is server code with stringify.

```
var express = require('express');
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var cors = require('cors');
const util = require('util');
const app = express();
var inflate = require('inflation')
var raw     = require('raw-body')
const json = require('body-parser').json();

app.use(cors())

const PORT = 3001
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Express server is running on port: ${PORT}!`);
});

app.get('/foo', (req,res) => {
  let dataUrl = 'www.apiURL.com/data.json';
  fetch(dataUrl)
  .then(x => {
    console.log(x.body._readableState.buffer.head.data.toString())
    let decompressed = inflate(x.body._readableState.buffer.toString());
res.send(JSON.stringify(x.body._readableState.buffer.head.data.toString()));
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

This is the client code.

```
  componentDidMount(){
fetch(serverUrl)
.then(res => {
  res.json()
  .then(body => {
    this.setState({
      clubData: body
    })
    console.log(res)
  });
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Why is the data being cut off? Doesn't matter when it is in string form because the buffer has been cut off too.

Answer (score 0):

Your client code should look like this.

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch(serverUrl)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(body => 
     this.setState({
       clubData: body
     }))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Let me know if this solves your issue and I can update the answer if there're other things I'm missing

Comment: Thanks Rowland! I'm getting the same response though. Can't figure out why the JSON is getting cut off!

Comment: Can you place console.log both in the server and the client  and update the question with the result?